# Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted and Ioncube

Tags: php, wordpress, ioncube

```
[STDERR] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 57 bytes) in /home/taktikoyuncu/public_html/wp-includes/pomo/entry.php on line 76
```

I use Wordpress on my website.
I tried to change max memory limit and it gives

> The file /home/xxx/public_html/wp-content/themes/xxxx/functions.php
>   cannot be decoded by this version of the ionCube Loader. If you are
>   the administrator of this site then please install the latest version
>   of the ionCube Loader. in Unknown on line 0

Comment: increase memory_limit

Comment: 33554432 is only 32meg, rather a small memory limit. Are you sure that the other bit of the error message is not more relevant i.e. Wrong version of IONCUBE

Comment: I upgrade memory limit to 64,128,256,512 but when i exceed 32 MB it gives "The file /home/xxx/public_html/wp-content/themes/xxxx/functions.php cannot be decoded by this version of the ionCube Loader. If you are the administrator of this site then please install the latest version of the ionCube Loader. in Unknown on line 0"          Yesterday it was working correctly.

Comment: Set `memory_limit` to `64M`

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, the file cannot be processed by the version of the Loader that you have in place. If you update to the latest Loader, or ask your host to do this for you, that should resolve. You can find the latest Loaders at https://loaders.ioncube.com